# Use an object created in another class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use in one class an object created in another class. Is there anyway to do that? I'm showing you the code:

In this class named Item I created an object at the end, named spellwand.

```
namespace RPG.Entities
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Damage { get; set; }
        public int MagicalDamage { get; set; }
        public int Defense { get; set; }
        public int Resistance { get; set; }

        public Item(string name, int damage, int magicalDamage, int defense, int resistance)
        {
            Name = name;
            Damage = damage;
            MagicalDamage = magicalDamage;
            Defense = defense;
            Resistance = resistance;
        }

        Item spellwand = new Item("Spellwand", 0, 12, 0, 0);
    }
```

Now, in this class Character I created the next method:

```
using RPG.Entities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace RPG.Entities
{
    public class Character
    {
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }

        public void AddItem(Item item)
        {
            Item.Add(item);
        }   
    }
}
```

Cool, now in the class Battle I'd like to call the object "spellwand" created at Item class.

```
namespace RPG.Entities
{
    public class Story
    {
        public void Battle()
        {

            Character eskilie = new Character("Eskilie", "Magician");
            eskilie.AddItem(spellwand);

    }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Btw, the error appearing at Battle is "The object spellwand does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Why would you want to create an `Item` inside the `Item` class?  Create it outside and you can use it.  Your `Item` class includes a constructor to allow you to create according to needs, so why create an internal one?

Comment: You need to learn about [variable scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/); that is a fundamental programming concept.

Comment: I'd like to create all the Items inside the item class because there are going to be a lot of them... I'd like to just call them at Main... if its possible

Comment: But your `List<Item>` collection is *outside* the Item class.  It is not going to take less code to create them inside the class.

Comment: Make it public : public Item spellwand

Comment: There is a significant difference between "can I" and should I.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is create the items in Story as a List like this:

```
namespace RPG.Entities
{
    public class Story
    {
        // Store all your possible game items here
        protected List<Item> GameItems = new List<Item>();

        public Story()
        {
            // Add your game items
            GameItems.Add(new Item("Spellwand", 0, 12, 0, 0));
            GameItems.Add(new Item("Axe", 0, 14, 0, 0));
        }

        public void Battle()
        {

            Character eskilie = new Character("Eskilie", "Magician");

            // Add item
            var spellwand = GameItems.Where(i => i.name == "Spellwand").FirstOrDefault();
            eskilie.AddItem(spellwand)
        }
    }
}
```

Then remove the new item from your Item class

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public int MagicalDamage { get; set; }
    public int Defense { get; set; }
    public int Resistance { get; set; }

    public Item(string name, int damage, int magicalDamage, int defense, int resistance)
    {
        Name = name;
        Damage = damage;
        MagicalDamage = magicalDamage;
        Defense = defense;
        Resistance = resistance;
    }

}
```

Ideally, you would have an ItemRepository class that would retrieve all your game items but hopefully this gives you an idea of the structure to start.